# How do I Convert a canvas into an image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

I am looking to convert a canvas to image in WPF. I am using RenderTargetBitMap for exporting and it is works great.

My problem is if canvas's height is more than max integer value, getting an exception in below code.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =new RenderTargetBitmap((int)canvas.Width,(int)canvas.Height,96d,96d,PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

The error message is

> "Value does not fall within the expected range"

So how can I export a canvas with height more than 39,000 px to image ?

Comment: Integer max value is 2,147,483,647. You have another problem. it's most probably limitation of direct x, that you can't have so large bitmaps. You need to scale it down before you render it.

Comment: this may help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222756/scaling-wpf-content-before-rendering-to-bitmap

Comment: Thanks for your response @XaverKapeller. You are correct, the issue is related to image size. I have tried to scale down the image. But the contents (text) are not readable after scaling down. Is there any other way to export a large canvas, other than bitmap image.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `Canvas` into a [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) control and set its dimensions to a more reasonable size. Once you have done that, you can simply create a scaled down image from that instead:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    (int)viewBox.Width,(int)viewBox.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Sheridan. I have tried with 'View Box'. But the contents (text) are not readable after scaling down. Could you please advise any other way to export a large canvas, other than bitmap image.